# How can i put more than one context in my remote hooks whit loopback?

Tags: loopback

I don't know how to put many ctx in beforeRemote hooks. And i don't know what means second paramether in that method "unused"?
I need to put some dates and values from request in beforeRemote.

```js
mymodel.beforeRemote('method',function(context,unused,next())  {
   
   //where can i forward my new value, and what is a 'unused'  ???
   next()
});
```

Comment: Can you describe your scenario in more detail? Why do you want to have multiple context objects? You say you need to 'put some dates and values from request'. Where do you want to put them?